# bash/shell pass array to function then loop?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, loops

When defining an Array directly in the function the below works as expected;

```
function each {
  local array=(1 2 3)
  len=${#array[*]}
  for (( i=0; i<len; i++ )); do
    echo ${array[$i]}
  done
}

each

# outputs;

1
2
3
```

But I can't figure out how to pass the array in as an argument and achieve the same output;

```
function each {
  local array=$1
  len=${#array[*]}
  for (( i=0; i<len; i++ )); do
    echo ${array[$i]}
  done
}

array=(1 2 3)
each array

# outputs;

array
```

Grateful for any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would pass the array elements as distinct positional parameters to the function:

```
function f() {
    local array = "$@";
    # ...
}

## calling your function
f ("${array[@]}")
```

Comment: thanks Costi, will close this as dupe though

Comment: I voted for closing it myself after realizing there's a complete discussion already clarifying this. :)